# is there any way to make this react component less verbose?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

So, i wrote a [test project](https://github.com/sombriks/vue-react-comparison/blob/master/my-react-project-3/src/views/Settings.jsx) to explore react, react-router and react-redux.

After i got everything working fine i laid my eyes again on `Settings.jsx` and i am wondering how could i make it less verbose and error prone:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Settings extends Component {
  state = { name: this.props.settings.name };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Settings</h1>
        <p>This is Settings page</p>
        My name is{" "}
        <input
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}/>
        <button onClick={e => this.props.changeName(this.state.name)}>
          Change
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapState = state => ({ settings: state.settings });
const mapDispatch = dispatch => {
  return {
    changeName(name) {
      dispatch({ type: "setName", name });
    }
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch
)(Settings);
```

My first idea was to convert it into a [functional component](https://devhints.io/react#other-components), but it's said that they don't have state and i need the state to locally handle the input.

Comment: Hi, It is ok the way you do. You could if you wish add the typing name state to your store and transform into functional component, but it is unnecessary I think.

However I recommend you to add all your actions in separated files for better readability. The main goal of redux is to give a clear visibility of all existing actions.

Comment: FYI - Functional components can have state by using hooks, which is as of now in alpha and introduced in v16.7 - ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators`, `connect` can be used as a decorator:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";

const mapState = state => ({ settings: state.settings });
const mapDispatch = dispatch => {
  return {
    changeName(name) {
      dispatch({ type: "setName", name });
    }
  };
};

@connect(mapState, mapDispatch)
export default class Settings extends Component {
  state = { name: this.props.settings.name };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Settings</h1>
        <p>This is Settings page</p>
        My name is{" "}
        <input
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}/>
        <button onClick={e => this.props.changeName(this.state.name)}>
          Change
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

small, but imho nice simplification

also, you could use concise syntax with your `mapDispatch`:

```
const mapDispatch = dispatch => ({
  changeName(name) {
    dispatch({ type: "setName", name });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this if you want to to add the typing text in store:

**Settings.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { changeName, typingName } from '../actions/settingsActions'
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const Settings = () => {
  const { changeName, typingName, typedName, submittedName } = this.props
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Settings</h1>
      <p>This is Settings page</p>
      My name is{" "}
      <input
        value={typedName}
        onChange={e => typingName(e.target.value)}/>
      <button onClick={changeName(submittedName)}>
        Change
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapState = state => ({ 
  typedName: state.typedName,
  submittedName: state.submittedName
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  typingName: x => dispatch(typingName(x)),
  changeName: x => dispatch(changeName(x))
})

export default connect(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch
)(Settings);
```

**settingsActions.js**

```
export const typingName = payload => ({
    type: 'TYPING_NAME',
    payload 
});

export const changeName = payload => ({
    type: 'CHANGE_NAME',
    payload 
});
```

**settingsReducer.js**

```
export const typingName = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
        case 'TYPING_NAME':
                return [...state, action.payload];

        default:
                return state;
  }
};

export const changeName = (state = '', action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
        case 'CHANGING_NAME':
                return action.payload;

        default:
                return state;
  }
};
```

You could maybe achieve something like this. But validating the typing state inside the component then sending the final result to the store as you did is a better idea I think, to avoid so much verbose.
Also you should of course create a constants file, but I guess you know already.